# Crash приложения Spring Boot при запуске из jar файла

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle, jar

Есть приложение `Spring Boot` и в IDE оно нормально работает и запускается.

Но если упаковать его в `.jar`  и запустить, то приложение падает с ошибкой:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build
>   ClassFile     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [classes!/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [classes!/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [classes!/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [classes!/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [classes!/:na]    at com.common.Application.main(Application.java:48)
>   [classes!/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [SpringBootExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [SpringBootExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [SpringBootExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [SpringBootExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na] Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build
>   ClassFile     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:88)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:176)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:723)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:219)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:186)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[classes!/:na]   ... 24 common frames omitted

Возможно где то несовместимые версии `Hibernate`  и `Spring`, но как это поправить не знаю, так же непонятно почем в IDE запускает, а из `.jar` - нет.

**build.gradle**

```
group 'SpringBootExample'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName ="com.common.Application"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Include dependent libraries in archive.
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    //Spring
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'


    //Hibernate
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '4.3.6.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.3.6.Final'


    //JSON
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'

    //Log4j
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'



    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.15.0-GA'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'

    //Postgres driver
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.0-801.jdbc4'


    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '8.0.36'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', name: 'ecj', version: '4.4.2'

}
```

**AppMainConfig.java**

```
package com.common.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@Configuration
public class AppMainConfig {

}
```

**HibernateConfig.java**

```
package com.common.config;

import com.common.dao.GenericDao;
import com.common.dao.entity.Avatar;
import com.common.dao.impl.PurchaseDao;
import com.common.util.log.Log;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException;
import javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class HibernateConfig {


    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        final String daoPackage = GenericDao.class.getPackage().getName();

        final LocalSessionFactoryBuilder localSessionFactoryBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(getDataSource());

        return localSessionFactoryBuilder
                .scanPackages(daoPackage)
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {


        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb");
        dataSource.setUsername("userName");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

}
```